# Same code working differently on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I hope you're doing great.

I'm having a hard time figuring this out. I'm using the same code for an agree to terms box and submit button but with different button images and links. I just copied the code for them to work in the same way.
The buttons are on the same page but take you to different checkout pages. The first code is working fine, it blocks the user to proceed if they don't check the agreement box but the second code even though it's the same code, it's not doing the job; it's letting people through without agreeing to the terms.

Below are both codes and you can see they're different because of their hyperlinks and button images.

This a great community. I'm a beginner, excuse me if it's an amateur question. I really hope you all can help me, I really appreciate it!

Thank you so much!

```js
<html>
<head>
<script>
 function disableSubmit() {
  document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
 }

  function activateButton(element) {

      if(element.checked) {
        document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false;
       }
       else  {
        document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
      }

  }
</script>
<center><button type="submit" id="submit" onclick="document.location.href='https://www.jvzoo.com/b/570‌​51/250513/13';"><img src="http://i.jvzoo.com/57051/250513/13" alt="Tube Cash Blueprint (2M)" border="0" alt="Submit"/></button></center>
</head>
<center><h6> Tube Cash Blueprint Agreement</h6></center>
<body onload="disableSubmit()">

 <center><input type="checkbox" name="terms" id="terms" onchange="activateButton(this)"/>  Check here to indicate that you have read and agreed to the terms of the <a target="_blank" href="https://johnmichaelmarketing.com/tbc-agreement/">Tube Cash Blueprint Costumer Agreement</a> </center>
<br/><br/>

</body>
</html>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
 function disableSubmit() {
  document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
 }

  function activateButton(element) {

      if(element.checked) {
        document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false;
       }
       else  {
        document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
      }

  }
</script>
<center><button type="submit" id="submit" onclick="document.location.href='https://www.jvzoo.com/b/57051/250467/13';"><img src="http://i.jvzoo.com/57051/250467/13" alt="Tube Cash Blueprint" border="0" alt="Submit"/></button></center>
</head>
<center><h6> Tube Cash Blueprint Agreement</h6></center>
<body onload="disableSubmit()">

 <center><input type="checkbox" name="terms" id="terms" onchange="activateButton(this)"/>  Check here to indicate that you have read and agreed to the terms of the <a target="_blank" href="https://johnmichaelmarketing.com/tbc-agreement/">Tube Cash Blueprint Costumer Agreement</a> </center>
<br/><br/>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working?  Here's your first page: https://jsfiddle.net/ky8muoh2/  And it works.  Here's your second page:  https://jsfiddle.net/rkwer6g0/  And it also works.  What's the problem?  (Side note: You *are* closing your `</head>` tag later than you should be, perhaps your browser is getting confused by that?  It should be closed after the script, not after the button.)

Comment: And to add to what @David said, you should move your first <center> ... </center line after the body tag.

Comment: Hello @David and rasmeister, thank you for answering! So, please head over https://jm.johnmichaelmarketing.com/tcb-order-jvz/ you can see that if you click on the $997 offer, you can't click on it before accepting the terms (that's the first code) now, when you go to the $597 offer (second code), you click on the order button and it takes you to the checkout page without having accepted the terms. It should do nothing if you don't accept. Thank you all, I'd appreciate your help on this

Comment: Hello David and @rasmeister, thank you for answering! So, please head over jm.johnmichaelmarketing.com/tcb-order-jvz you can see that if you click on the $997 offer, you can't click on it before accepting the terms (that's the first code) now, when you go to the $597 offer (second code), you click on the order button and it takes you to the checkout page without having accepted the terms. It should do nothing if you don't accept. Thank you all, I'd appreciate your help on this

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the same id for 2 elements.

This id:

```
<button type="submit" id="submit" onclick="document.location.href='https://www.jvzoo.com/b/57051/250467/13';" disabled=""><img src="https://i.jvzoo.com/57051/250467/13" alt="Tube Cash Blueprint" border="0"></button>
```

is clashing with this:

```
<button type="submit" id="submit" onclick="document.location.href='https://www.jvzoo.com/b/570&zwnj;&#8203;51/250513/13';"><img src="https://i.jvzoo.com/57051/250513/13" alt="Tube Cash Blueprint (2M)" border="0"></button>
```

Just change the ids and it will work.
Now you have to write a different function for each id, or use a `name` instead to be able to use them in both

Quick and dirty solution - copy functions, change id:

```
<script>
  function disableSubmit1() {
      document.getElementById("submit1").disabled = true;
  }

  function activateButton1(element) {
      if(element.checked) {
          document.getElementById("submit1").disabled = false;
      }
      else  {
          document.getElementById("submit1").disabled = true;
      }
  }

  function disableSubmit2() {
      document.getElementById("submit2").disabled = true;
  }

  function activateButton2(element) {
      if(element.checked) {
          document.getElementById("submit2").disabled = false;
      }
      else  {
          document.getElementById("submit2").disabled = true;
     }
  }
</script>

<!-- button 1 -->

<button type="submit" id="submit1" disabled="" onclick="alert('submission1')">B1</button>

<input type="checkbox" name="terms" id="terms1" onchange="activateButton1(this)" /> 


<!-- button 2 -->

<button type="submit" id="submit2" disabled="" onclick="alert('submission2')">B2</button>

<input type="checkbox" name="terms" id="terms2" onchange="activateButton2(this)" />
```

Comment: Hello @brunofitas! Thanks a lot for your help, so you suggest I change the id=terms for somethig else in the other code? like id=conditions? Thanks again

Comment: Sorry, I copied the wrong buttons :D. I edited my asnwer. You want to change the id of submit. Both buttons have submit as id.

Comment: Thank you @brunofitas, I changed them but I still can't get it to work. Can you write me a sample code with my code? So I can take it as an example please? I really appreciate your help, I'm getting frustrated here haha

Comment: Close question if it helps ;-)

Comment: Haha thank you @brunofitas, they're two separate buttons. Do I split the code?

Comment: Just create 2 functions for now. It will work fine. But you should learn how to use ```name``` and custom ```attribute```. This way you only had to create one function that by reading the custom attribute would make changes on a named group... Jquery would be even better. But since you're starting out, you'll have time to learn it.

Comment: It's still not working @brunofitas :( I thought it might but no.. it still loads without checking the box. I changed the id as you showed me

Answer (score 0):

You have two html tag in one document. When i trace your code with my firefox inspector you second code are as an srcipt of the first one. What i saw and copy:

```
<br><br>

<script type="text/javascript">
    <html>
 <head>
 <script>
 function disableSubmit() {
 document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
 }

 function activateButton(element) {

  if(element.checked) {
    document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false;
   }
   else  {
    document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
  }

 }
</script>
```

If you want your code work remove `<html><head><script>` from the first of second code.